# How can I queue functions in Appscript?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, web-applications, google-sheets-api, v8

I have an AppScript WebApp that is used by several users simultaneously. The web app runs functions that all edit the same sheet, but I do not want the script to attempt to run all functions called by multiple users at the same time. Is there some sort of FIFO system that will run the functions one at a time in the order they were called?

Currently using the code below, but since it is using sleep, there are instances where functions do not get ran on the correct order.

```
/**
   * This function queues a callback function if the script is busy
   * NOTE: This function might be placed on another file, since it is not dependant on the Worksheet
   * @param {object} functionToCall is the function to queue
   */
  static queueScriptFunction(functionToCall){
    let success = false;
    let firstLock = LockService.getScriptLock();
    while(!success){
      success = firstLock.tryLock(0);
      if(success){
        console.log("Success");
        functionToCall();
      }
      else{
      console.log("Occupied");
      Utilities.sleep(45000)
      }
    } 
  }
```

Comment: Take a look at [Lock Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/lock/lock-service)

Comment: If two or more functions are running tryLock(), while another function is running, which will  be the order in which the lock will be passed?

Comment: Apps Script is JavaScript and thus single-threaded — functions run in the order they are called. Concurrent _instances_ of a script may compete for the same resources though. To understand how locking works, see [Lock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lock_(computer_science)).

Comment: How is the webapp published? [Edit] to provide webapp published information as written in  the [tag info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info).